# aggregation queries on nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following json object and I am trying to find out what all questions total answers

```
{
   "responses":[
      {
         "question":{
            "name":"Please rate your experience"
         },
         "answers":[
            {
               "name":"4/10"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "question":{
            "name":"Designation"
         },
         "answers":[
            {
               "name":"Student"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "question":{
            "name":"Did you attempt any experiments ?"
         },
         "answers":[
            {
               "name":"No"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Here I would  like to get the count of each unique answer to its corresponding question

I tried out following aggregation query

```
{
   "aggs":{
      "questions":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"responses.question.name",
            "order":{
               "_count":"asc"
            },
            "size":0
         },
         "aggs":{
            "answers":{
               "terms":{
                  "field":"responses.answers.name"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is listing count of all the available answers for every questions as below

```
{
   "took":59,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":1,
      "max_score":1,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_index":"post_question",
            "_type":"feedback",
            "_id":"AV5qHAAXBWUeGnRiAgw2",
            "_score":1,
            "_source":{
               "responses":[
                  {
                     "question":{
                        "name":"Please rate your experience"
                     },
                     "answers":[
                        {
                           "name":"4/10"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "question":{
                        "name":"Designation"
                     },
                     "answers":[
                        {
                           "name":"Student"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "question":{
                        "name":"Did you attempt any experiments ?"
                     },
                     "answers":[
                        {
                           "name":"No"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "aggregations":{
      "questions":{
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
         "sum_other_doc_count":0,
         "buckets":[
            {
               "key":"Designation",
               "doc_count":1,
               "answers":{
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                  "buckets":[
                     {
                        "key":"4/10",
                        "doc_count":1
                     },
                     {
                        "key":"No",
                        "doc_count":1
                     },
                     {
                        "key":"Student",
                        "doc_count":1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"Did you attempt any experiments ?",
               "doc_count":1,
               "answers":{
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                  "buckets":[
                     {
                        "key":"4/10",
                        "doc_count":1
                     },
                     {
                        "key":"No",
                        "doc_count":1
                     },
                     {
                        "key":"Student",
                        "doc_count":1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"Please rate your experience",
               "doc_count":1,
               "answers":{
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                  "buckets":[
                     {
                        "key":"4/10",
                        "doc_count":1
                     },
                     {
                        "key":"No",
                        "doc_count":1
                     },
                     {
                        "key":"Student",
                        "doc_count":1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Can somebody look into and help me out

Answer (score 0):

What is your datamodel? Does it only consist of `responses`? If so, consider indexing each response as a separate document. Then you could do a `terms` aggregation on the question and then within that `top hits` aggregation to group the answers by question. You will see the counts of the answers in the `hits.total`. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: Yes along with responses it contains other fields {"lab_name" : "Data structures", "exp_name" : "arrays", "responses" : []}, and there is relationship between responses with other two fileds

Comment: It seems a quite complicated data model. This means you will have to write more complicated queries. Anyway, you can also use the top hits aggregation for nested objects. So you could make the whole responses field a nested field.